# php return a specific row from query

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible in php to return a specific row of data from a mysql query?

None of the fetch statements that I've found return a 2 dimensional array to access specific rows.

I want to be able to return only 1 specific row, kinda like mysql_result... except for entire row instead of 1 cell in a row.

I don't want to loop through all the results either, I already know how to do that I just thought that there might be a better way that I'm not aware of. Thanks

Comment: You need a better SQL query apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) to your mysql statement. And it will return only data you need. Like following:

```
-- returns 1 row after 2 row
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 2, 1
```

Comment: This works, I wish I had thought of this. I use limit all the time but it didn't occur to me to use it this time. Thanks Ivan

Comment: You should always use a query that returns as few rows as needed. Doing this in the code instead of in the query is almost double-work.

Answer (score 3):

For example, [`mysql_data_seek()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) and [`mysqli_stmt_data_seek()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.data-seek.php) allow you to skip forward in a query result to a certain row.

If you are interested in one certain row only, why not adapt the query to return only the row you need (e.g. via a more specific `WHERE` clause, or `LIMIT`)? This would be more resource-effective.

Comment: Without getting into details the situation does not alow me to be more specific.